# How get a session from a servlet to another servlet?

Tags: java, session, servlets

Hello every body i have a problem , I don't know how to pass my session from a servlet to 1 other.

This is my session in the first servlet :

String mail=request.getParameter("mail");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");

```
    dao.connexion(mail);

    Utilisateur utilisateur=dao.connexion(mail);


    if(utilisateur!=null){


        //si le le password correspont il se connecte

         if(utilisateur.testPass(password)) {

        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
     session.setAttribute("id", session.getId());

        session.setAttribute("utilisateur", utilisateur);
```

How can i get it in my second servlet?

I tried with this but doesn't work:

int idMedia= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idMedia"));

```
    List<Commentaire> mesCommentaires =daoCom.afficheCommentairesSurUnFilm(idMedia);


    HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);

    Utilisateur u= (Utilisateur) session.getAttribute("utilisateur");

    request.setAttribute("id", u.getId());
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `"utilisateur" != "utilsiateur"`. Voting to close for typo. Use constants for your shared attributes.

Comment: I corrected the error but doesn't work :(

Comment: Are both servlets part of the same webapp? Have you proven youexecuted the first servlet, and entered the if block, before executing the second one? Why don't you use a constant as I suggested?

Comment: yes are servlets of same app . The if don't block the session is just for a check .Is more easier with a session because i need to cross a lot of jsp before

Answer (score 0):

First Sevlet -> session.setAttribute("utilisateur", utilisateur);

Second Servlet -> session.getAttribute("utilisateur");